# RDLC - how to force textbox to be located at page bottom

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdlc

Hello I have to put textbox (with user name and place for signature) at the very bottom page.
I tried few ways, also experimented with footer but this didnt work to me.

I have quite complicated layout:

1. report header (logo, address etc)
2. tablix #1
3. textbox with signature (Im speaking of)
4. tablix #2 
   ...

Tablix #1 might complete over 1-5 pages - so I need put textbox (3) at bottom of the same page when tablix #1 ends.

Can someone advise how to archieve that ?

Comment: The textbox should be a footer in the report.  See if this helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-or-remove-a-page-header-or-footer-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I tried that but then it was repeated on every page. I need it only on 1 page between 2 tables

Comment: You have to create a new section so you get a different footer.  just like a work document.

Comment: @jdweng How to create new section ?